# Determine whether an NSMenu is opened

Tags: objective-c, nsmenu

I have an NSMenu which opens when a user clicks an NSStatusItem in the status bar. How can I determine if the NSMenu is opened (expanded) or not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `NSMenuDelegate` protocol to handle `menuWillOpen` and `menuWillClose` messages. Use `menuWillOpen` to set a boolean that states that the menu is open, and `menuWillClose` to turn it off.

---

**Update:** Looks like `menuWillClose:` is no longer an available delegate method. Use `menuDidClose:` instead.

Comment: Thank you! But it still doesn't work. What I did is add <NSMenuDelegate> to the interface file. Then in .m file I added two methods:                                          `-(void) menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *) theMenu {
 
 isClosed = NO;
 
}`    and   `-(void) menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *) theMenu {
 
 isClosed = NO;
 
}`    Is that enough? What did I do wrong?

Comment: You have to call `[menu setDelegate:self]` in your `awakeFromNib` method or something.

Comment: No problem! I've made the mistake of forgetting to set delegates many a time, often with bizarre results... good luck! ;)

Comment: Due to the current Mac Developer Library there is no `menuWillClose` method but a `menuDidClose:` method instead. Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMenuDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSMenuDelegate